# How to use drupal fancy box

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drupal, fancybox

I have downloaded fancy box from Drupal website and installed as per the instruction. Now I want to add a content with fancybox effects. How can I do that? I didn't saw anything on Add Content .So How to use fancybox in Drupal?

Answer (score 0):

If it's a recent version of the fancybox module, all you should have to do is enable the module, then alter your theme so that links you want to pop-up under fancy box have the class `imagefield-fancybox`. This class appears to be hard-coded in the the `fancybox/js/fancybox.js` file, at least in the 7.x-1.x-dev branch.